# Cycling between "No module named functools_lru_cache" and "cannot import name cbook" errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am completely new to Python but I enjoyed it very much. I start with Python 2.7 before migrating to Python 3 since many applications for work have to do with Python 2.7.

I have quite sadly many version of python2.7 on my MacBook. One from Apple, one from Homebrew, one from Anaconda. I have pip version 18.0 installed.

I wanted to install many modules (scipy in particular) and I ran into the following problem.

On the console:

```
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 29 2018, 20:59:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

`>>> import matplotlib`

I get the **error** message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import matplotlib
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 130, in 
>       from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 29, in 
>       from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/fontconfig_pattern.py", line 28, in 
>       from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
>   ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache

I looked on the web and found the solution for that by typing:

`pip install --user matplotlib`

Now when I do:

`>>> import matplotlib`

I get the message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import matplotlib
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 126, in 
>       from . import cbook
>
> ImportError: cannot import name cbook

There is a confusion on the web about how to solve this problem. Is there still hope I can get back running?

Comment: Did you install matplotlib 3.0 in a python 2.7 environment?

Comment: I can't say. I launched pip with several packages to install including matplotlib, ipython and jupyter. I wanted scipy. And I got these error messages... I edited my .profile to remove the PATH associated with the different python2.7 i had but with no avail!

Comment: The usual way is to either use pip3 for installing to the default python3. Or if you are using anaconda to activate the environment for which you want to use pip and then do `python -m pip install [package]`. However when in anaconda you could also just `conda install [package]` or `conda install -n myenv package` with `myenv` being the environment for which to install the package. It's really hard to help here because its not clear what environment you are using or want to update.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I don't know how to start anaconda. The only app is the "conda navigator" and I don't see where to type a command. I am lost... I understand Homebrew. I looked "which python" and I got /usr/local/bin/python. I set "brew uninstalled python3".  I would like to restart everything...

Comment: Anaconda navigator gives you a GUI for what you can otherwise do in the command line of your choice. So in principle you can also use the GUI to install whichever package you need. The important part is to always use the python from the distribution you want to work with - it doesn't help if you installed some package with anaconda but then start the homebrew python.

Comment: OK! I found the anaconda folder and started the python there and no matplotlib problem. Now, how do I set this version to be my standard version. I have to edit the .profile and set the path I guess...

Comment: Yes. I'm no mac expert, so I can't help with that, but it should be a standard procedure to be found via googling something like "mac change path" or similar.

Comment: You have to add the command: export PYTHONPATH="~/anaconda/bin/":$PYTHONPATH to the .profile and everything runs.... so far!  Thank you again ImportanceOfBeingErnest! And don't forget to start in a new terminal to activate .profile!